# rewritebase not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using the rewrite url , And its working fine ,

But if do url rewriting then my CSS and JS not working bcoz i am call my script / css somthing like href='css/style.css' ,

I tried direct url instead of siteurl , Then css working ,

i finally desired ed to use rewritebase but for me its not working , if put this snippet then totally url rewiring not working,

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~myfolder/
    RewriteRule ^booking/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?price=$1&pass=$2
```

May i know ,

How to declare  the RewriteBase in .HTACCESS FILE

Thanks

Comment: can you also add the rewrite rules and the physical path prefix?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
   RewriteCond !\.(js|css)$
```

To your htaccess (after rewritebase) and it should work, also feel free to add image types to this expression.

I don't know what your application does, but I'm wondering why you would make price a variable that can be injected via the url. If this is part of a webshop or something, than passing along a price this way is a very very bad idea.

Comment: no ya..This site for booking taxi..so no probs. no money transaction

Comment: hi ,
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|images|js)/
RewriteRule ^rule_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)?.html$ rule.php?price=$1&pass=$2

This is saying PAGE  NOT FOUND